# Считаются ли названия игр произведением искусства? :)

Tags: орфография

Если считаются, то тогда следует использовать кавычки в названии компьютерных играх — да и не только в компьютерных.

Например, я придумал такое предложение.

Главный дизайнер игры «Grand Theft Auto V» будет судиться с Владимиром Путиным.

В данном предложении, если Вы не знаете, Grand Theft Auto (или же сокращенно GTA) — название игры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запутались в терминах. Произведения искусства тут ни при чем.

Наименования делятся на: собственные и нарицательные.

Собственные наименования делятся на:

1.Имена собственные.

2.**Реальные собственные наименования**, которые **не заключаются в кавычки** (географические названия (топонимы, микротопонимы), названия архитектурных сооружений, учреждений и т.д.).

3.**Условные собственные наименования**, которые **заключаются в кавычки** (названия литературных, музыкальных произведений, СМИ, компаний и т.д.).

Названия компьютерных игр - условные собственные наименования, которое закавычиваются, не считая тех, которые написаны латиницей.

С помощью кавычек и прописных букв можно передавать разные смысловые оттенки. Например: *«квартал красных фонарей»* - образное название квартала с определенной профессиональной ориентацией, который может быть в любом городе. Теперь давайте пофантазируем.

квартал Красных Фонарей – официальное название квартала, нанесенное на карту, микротопоним

квартал «Красных фонарей» невозможен, так как есть согласование (условное название было бы квартал «Красные фонари»)

квартал красных фонарей – буквальное значение, с красными фонарями, которых там сейчас нет

Квартал красных фонарей – топоним, название города или страны

"Квартал красных фонарей" - название фирмы

Comment: Не запутались мы в терминах. Я отталкиваюсь от заголовка вопроса.

Comment: Автор спрашивает, можно ли приравнять названия игр к названиям произведений искусства, потому что в правилах употребления кавычек игры не упоминаются - там фигурируют произведения искусства, ордена, производственные марки и т.д. А на самом деле, чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, его надо формулировать шире - о собственных наименованиях.

Answer (score 6):

Отвечаю на вопрос в заголовке: названия игр произведениями искусства не являются! Равно как и названия книг: роман "Война и мир" - несомненно, произведение искусства (искусства слова - литературы), но название - нет.

О знаках. Названия компьютерных игр пишутся с большой буквы и в кавычках. Но, действительно, названия, написанные латиницей, в кавычки обычно не берутся.

Comment: Да, я в СМИ встречал написание именно без кавычек.

Answer (score 2):

Названия написанные латиницей в кавычки не берутся.

Answer (score 1):

А разве в кавычки берутся названия только произведений искусства? Названия периодических изданий, например, заключаются в кавычки. Но ни те, ни другие (издания и их названия) произведениями искусства не являются.

Comment: Отчего Вы так считаете? Люди, работающие над фильмом, творят да творят. Следовательно, это искусство. Создавая игры, нужно тоже иметь воображение.

Comment: Tagirix,прочитайте внимательно свой заголовок к вопросу. Вы там говорите не о играх, а о названиях игр как произведении искусства. Нужно поправить заголовок: являются ли компьютерные игры произведениями искусства? Или: нужно ли заключать в кавычки названия компьютерных игр?

Comment: При чём тут фильмы? Их вы относите к периодическим изданиям?
  Газету можно считать произведением искусства?
  А разве кондитер не творит?. Торт - тоже произведение искусства?